# structs in different headers refer to each other

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I want to have a struct that contains a pointer to another struct which in turn has a function pointer with the function argument being a pointer to the first type of struct but I'm struggling to resolve the references. The struct definitions are in different header files and must be available to other code in the full project.

In a simplified example, in main I have:

```
#include "a.h"

typedef struct {
    int x;

    int (*func)(a_t * a);

    int y;
} z_t;
```

In a.h:

```
#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_

#include "z.h"

typedef struct {
    int b;
    int c;

    z_t * z;
} a_t;

#endif /* A_H_ */
```

and in z.h:

```
#ifndef Z_H_
#define Z_H_

#include "a.h"

typedef struct {
    int x;

    int (*func)(a_t * a);

    int y;
} z_t;

#endif /* Z_H_ */
```

I end up with circular #includes and type a_t is unknown in z.h

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

In C, you can have a circular reference among two or more structures, or from a structure to itself. Note that the reference can be by pointer only: one structure X cannot embed an instance of another while simultaneously X embeds an instance of Y. However, X can have a pointer to Y, while Y can point to X, or embed a copy of X.

The mechanism which allows a circular reference in C is the *incomplete struct type*. In C you can use `struct` in a declaration, without defining the body of the struct, like this:

```
struct foo *bar;  // foo has never been seen before.
```

The `foo` identifier is the "struct tag".  A later re-declaration of the same struct tag in the same scope which *does* include a body will complete the type:

```
struct foo { int member; };  // foo is now complete
```

With this we can do:

```
struct list_node {
  struct list_node *next, *previous; // self reference
};

struct foo {
  struct bar *bar_ptr;
};

struct bar {
  struct foo *foo_ptr; // mutual references
};
```

In your code, you haven't used a single struct tag; all your struct types are anonymous, and you are relying on `typedef` aliases. The above referential tricks cannot be played out using `typedef` names; the struct tags are essential.

Only a struct which has a tag can be declared two or more times: incomplete the first times, and then completely. The declaration of a struct with no tag is anonymous; such a declaration invents a new, unique struct type each time it appears.